# How to set value coming from json in angularjs drop down list

Tags: angularjs, json, dropdown

In my edit page, what I need is to show the value in drop down list where the value is coming from a json file. I am able to get the value in html file but struggling in showing this value as selected.

Here's the html code:

```
<select class="form-control" name="manufacturer" ng-change="loadModels(cameraDetails.manufacture_id.id);" ng-model="cameraDetails.manufacture_id" ng-options="manufacturer.name for manufacturer in manufacturers" required>
    <option value="">{{'PLEASE_SELECT' | translate}}</option>
</select> 
{{cameraDetails.manufacture_id}}  // Here I am getting the value.
```

json file:

```
{
    "ip": "10.103.01.0",
    "name": "Camera axiss",
    "description": "Description text here",
    "manufacture_id": "SONY",
    "modelId": "Model XYZ001",
    "user_name": "user",
    "password": "pass",
    "isEnableCamera": true,
    "hasMasking": true,
    "hasPresetCamera":true,

    "userGroup": {
        "userGroupIds": "Group 2"
    }

}
```

I saw similar issue ([How do I set default value of select box in angularjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18380951/how-do-i-set-default-value-of-select-box-in-angularjs)) but that dint worked for me.

any help would be a great help.

Comment: It seems that `cameraDetails.manufacture_id` not maching with option values in drop down.  Try ``ng-options="manufacturer.manufacture_id as manufacturer.name for manufacturer in manufacturers" ``

Comment: When you are doing the ng repeat why are you keeping the value="" try passing some value and then check.

Answer (score -1):

You can do it in following way

```
 <select class="form-control" name="manufacturer" ng-change="loadModels(cameraDetails.manufacture_id.id);" ng-model="cameraDetails.manufacture_id"  required>
                               <option ng-repeat="m in manufacturers" value="m.ip">{{m.name}}</option>
                            </select>
```

Here is working example http://jsfiddle.net/phd975zo/

Comment: My question was  "I am able to get the value in html file but struggling in showing this value as selected.".. @jitender