# How to set default selected value in Angular Chosen?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-chosen

I have a `select` tag to which I am applying angular chosen.

This is my `select` tag

```
<select name="rname" id="rname" ng-model="rname" ng-init="rname='CustomReport'" 
   ng-options="key as value for (key , value) in reportsValuesOptions track by key" chosen>
        <option value="">---Select---</option>
</select>
```

The above `select` tag is getting populated from below object

```
$scope.reportsValuesOptions = {'Cash Position Report':'Cash Position Report','Detail Report':'Detail Report','Reconciliation Report':'Reconciliation Report','Summary Report':'Summary Report','Sweep Report':'Sweep Report','FCCS/FBPS Detail Report':'FCCS/FBPS Detail Report','CustomReport':'Custom Report Name'};
```

The object is a pair of values and options for `select` tag where **the `key` is `options tags value` and the `value` is the `option tag text`**

Now I want to set the default value of the `select` tag to `'CustomReport'` as its `option value` and `'Custom Report Name'` as its `option text` from the above object, using `ng-init`.

I tried doing `ng-init="rname='CustomReport'"`, but it doesn't work

How to set its value from object's key value pair?

**[FULL EXAMPLE](https://jsfiddle.net/Kunalh/snzecjyz/2/)**

Comment: its better to do it from js rather than from html.. so just initialize the `$scope.rname = default-element`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your solution is since you are giving an object and AngularJS is mostly designed for arrays it causes AngularJS not to be able to track them properly. You probably wanted to write a shorter object for `reportsValueOptions` but it should be an array of objects which has a form similar to the following:

```
[
  {label: 'First Label', value:'first-option'},
  {label: 'Second Label', value:'second-option'}
]
```

Here is the modified version of your [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7ga5g87h/) with modified object that also shows which one is selected.

You can also learn more about problems with objects here: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions#complex-models-objects-or-collections-

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use ng-init like this

```
<select ng-init="somethingHere = options[0]" 
        ng-model="somethingHere" 
        ng-options="option.name for option in options">
</select>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21931119
nice copy paste skills.. Please give reference if you will copy some elses answer.

Comment: @Vicheanak I am still not getting it. From what you have said I tried this

`ng-init="rname = reportsValuesOptions['CustomReport']"`

but didn't work. What wrong am I doing?

Comment: this would not work in case of `options ` gets fetched from `ajax`