# Set Selected Option In Dropdown in AngularJS onload

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

In Angularjs, I have a DropDown:

```
<select ng-model="category" ng-change="categoryChanged(category)" class="form-control" 
data-ng-options="category as category.name for category in categories">
        <option value="">Select Category</option>
</select>
```

And I have a controller:

```
app.controller('searchBoxController', ['$scope', '$location', '$routeParams', 'categoryService', function ($scope, $location, $routeParams, categoryService) {
        categoryService.getParentCategory().$promise.then(
        function (model) {
            $scope.categories = model;
            $scope.category.id = $routeParams.categoryId;// Which is coming as "1"
        },
        function (error) {

        });

        $scope.categoryChanged = function (category) {
             alert(category.id);
        };
}]);
```

`$routeParams.categoryId` is coming as "1" but still it is not setting the selected option in the dropdown.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I set default value of select box in angularjs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18380951/how-do-i-set-default-value-of-select-box-in-angularjs)

Comment: You have to declare `$scope.category = {};` at the beginning of your controller.

Comment: @xkcd149 Sorry to say but my question is not duplicate. I had only id from  $routeParams whereas the question which is marked as duplicate is focusing on whole object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to change `ng-model` directive when `promise` operation is end.

```
<select  ng-model="category" ng-change="categoryChanged(category)" class="form-control" data-ng-options="category as category.name for category in categories">
    <option value="">Select Category</option>
</select>
```

Suppose you have `var id = $routeParams.categoryId` and its value is `2` for example. You have to find `category` from `categories` where `category.id` is `2`. For this, the simpliest method is to use a `filter` method.

```
$scope.category = $scope.categories.filter(function(item){
        return item.id==$scope.id;
})[0];
```

Please take a look to [working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ionutmihai1995/100ho18L/178/)

Comment: I was not the downvoter, but I can see your given solution doesn't solve OP's question. You just set the `category` to the first item of the array instead of the one with the given id of the `$routeParams`

Answer (score 2):

Your `categories` variable is an array of objects, while you set the `ng-model` to an object with only an id. Because it is a whole new object, angular doesn't see it as a match of the category in your array, and won't select the correct one.

The solution is to set the `$scope.category` to the matching object of the array instead of creating a new one:

```
var id = $routeParams.categoryId;
// Find the category object with the given id and set it as the selected category
for (var i = 0; i < $scope.categories.length; i++){
    if ($scope.categories[i].id == id) {
        $scope.category = $scope.categories[i];
    }
}
```